# YII booster widget not appear in server

Tags: php, yii, widget, yii-booster

I need help here. I have a system developed with Yii framework. I used Yii Bootstrap and Yii Booster for the extensions. However, the booster widgets that I have implemented inside the system is not appearing when I uploaded the files into the LINUX server. It works fine in my laptop (development environment). The textarea, modal, tbselect2 all works well. However, it's not appear on the server side.

example:

```
//booster for tbckeditor
$this->widget('booster.widgets.TbCKEditor',array(
        'model'=>$model,                # Data-Model (form model)
        'attribute'=>'content',         # Attribute in the Data-Model
        'editorOptions' => array(
            'plugins' => 'basicstyles,toolbar,enterkey,entities,floatingspace,wysiwygarea,indentlist,list,dialog,dialogui,button,indent,fakeobjects',
        )
 ) ); 

//booster for tbselect2
$this->widget('booster.widgets.TbSelect2',array(
            'model' => $model,
            'attribute' => 'job_cat_id',
            'data' => CHtml::listData(AdmJobCat::model()->findAll(array('order'=>'jc_title ASC')), 'jc_id', 'jc_title'),
            'options' => array('placeholder' => '--Please Select--','width' => '100%', 'allowClear'=>true,),
            'htmlOptions' => array('multiple' => 'multiple'),
        )
);

    <?php $this->beginWidget('booster.widgets.TbModal', array('id' => 'withdrawModal')); ?>
        <div class="modal-header">
            <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
            <h4>Withdraw Application(s)</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="container-modal">
        <?php 
        $this->renderPartial('form/_withdraw_form'); //calling external form
        ?>
        </div>
    <?php
    $this->endWidget();  //end modal widget
    ?>
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: hi, i didnt get any error, the widget just didnt appear. It appears normal textarea and dropdown menu.

Comment: can you check browser console log, it seems some javascript issue is there

Comment: yeah, 2 errors appear: uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
create:157, Uncaught ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined. but how to fix this? i thought it was part of booster ext itself?

Comment: where the script file located? in asset folder? if yes then check the permission of asset folder also try after removing folders in asset folder.

Comment: yes, it's inside the assets folder. it's the JS file problem as u mentioned. let me try to remove all the folders inside.

Comment: what is the right permission for the asset folder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96845/discussion-between-chetan-ameta-and-verlee).